# Webp image cropping in paperclip

Tags: paperclip, webp

I have a functionality like image crop in our site which is working fine for pixel format images. Now I need to add crop for webp format images. For every pixel format image that has been uploaded, we are creating a webp format image style. Can someone suggest me how to crop those webp versions automatically if I cropped its pixel format image?

I tried two ways.

1. I tried to do direct crop for the webp version by specifying the crop_x crop_y crop_height crop_width for the image version and reprocessing it again. This didn't work.
2. Also I tried to delete the existing webp version for that image and again tried to create the webp version with the cropped pixel format image. In this way the webp version is getting created locally but not getting created in s3.